# How to read dynamic website content in java

Tags: java

As per the html the source code is:

{result.data}

While requesting the URL result.data is set with 100 and am able to see the value as 100 in the browser. Where as while I am trying to execute the java program with the same url request I am unable to see the value as I have seen in browser.

URL url = new URL(site)
url.openConnection() etc..

I wanted to get the same content as I have seen in the browser through java program.

Comment: "Here am not able to read the div values" *not able* meaning?

Comment: can you elaborate a little more about the issue  ?

Comment: If you're interested in the data, why don't you just use the same RESTful API as the one the angularjs application uses, and thus get back JSON, that is structured and easy to parse? To have the dynamically rendered HTML, you'd need a Java browser that is able to load and execute JavaScript.

Comment: @RC not able means --> While viewing the source code I am not able to see the information where as when I press F12/inspect in chrome I can see in html. The same data whatever I am able to see in inspect tool, the same I wanted to read in java program.

Comment: @VivekGupta: To make it simple I wanted to read the same content as I do in F12 or inspect.

Comment: @RajeshM So, you are saying you are able to get everything except `div` ?

Comment: @JBNizet I have restrictions to use Restful APIs because of some standards that we have internally. Can you elaborate bit more about java browser

Comment: @Ravi Yep. Because all those are static content and div is driving from backend

Comment: @RajeshM sorry, but that is BS. You need to make HTTP requests either way. So make HTTP requests to the appropriate JSON API URL, instead of trying to run an AngularJS application.

Comment: @RajeshM I don't think, if anything to do with static or dynamic content, because at last everything will be static only.

Comment: @Ravi <div class="header">
                <p><span>Number</span>{{result.data['status']}}</p>
            </div>    Here result.data is driving from backend. When I see this in Java/View source directly I am not able to see the value

Comment: @RajeshM this looks to be source code ,if this is what you get in element tab, then what do you see in browser ? Don't say, you see numbers there.

Comment: @Ravi Sorry I didn't get you. I am able to see some values are rendering in result.data place. But where as while I am trying to read the URL from the java program I am getting the source code but not the value

Comment: Any help please

Comment: I already gave help. An andular application gets its data from a RESTful API, in JSON (typically). You're interested in the data. So just use the same RESTful API as the angular application in Java, instead of trying to execute  an angular application and to parse its HTML view. That's the whole point of an API-based application.

Answer (score 0):

To what i understand, you want to do one of the below things :

1. Instead of reading the result line by line, you want to parse it as an `XML` to as to traverse to `div`(s) and other `html` tags.

   - For this purpose i would suggest you to use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library.
2. When you hit the URL: `www.abcd.com/number=500` in browser, it loads an empty div and on load it fetches data from somewhere, this data which it fetches on load, you want to fetch this using java ?

   - For this, there must be some js in the resulting page, which is fetching data by hitting some service on page load, you will need to look up in the page to know the service details and instead of hitting this URL (`www.abcd.com/number=500`) you will need to hit that service to get data.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to that code repository. Even I am not sure whats it calling.  any other way?

Comment: hit F12 on your page -> go to the network Tab -> refresh page again, you will see all the network calls listed there ...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very descriptive, but I guess you are trying to scrape data from the site.
You can use the following libraries for this task:

1. Jaunt (http://jaunt-api.com)
2. Jsoup (http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)
3. HTMLUnit

Comment: <div class="header"> <p><span>Number</span>{{result.data['status']}}</p> I want to see the value of result.data in java program but, that's not happening now.

Comment: Please update your question with the expected and actual output so that we can help you better. I am very sure Jsoup will help you with your use case. Go through its doc once.

Comment: @AnkitKumarSigh didn't worked for me. Still I am seeing the same result.data while printing. I am expecting 123 in place of this

Comment: @AnkitKumarSingh JSoup can't possibly help. It doesn't load and execute JavaScript as a browser does. And all the content is generated using JavaScript.

Comment: @JBNizet any help please?